# How to filter posts by using multiple category?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I tried everywhere but I can't find any solution :( , I want to search posts by using the category checkbox for example, if the user checks the photography and drawing category it only shows posts that have $category_slug=photography OR $category_slug=drawing but it only works if I check one category type if I select multiple category types it doesn't return anything. Please help

**blade**

```xml
@if (isset($categories))
  @foreach ($categories as $category)
    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="common_selector category" name="cate[]" value="{{ $category->slug }}">
        {{$category->name }}
      </label>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

**Controller**

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    $txtSearch = $request->input('q');
    if (isset($txtSearch)) {
        $query = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', "%$txtSearch%")->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    } else {       
        $query = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC');
        if ($request->has('cate')) {
            $categoryType = $request->input('cate');
            foreach ($categoryType as $category) {
                $query->where('category_slug', $category);
            }
        }
    }

    $queryResults = $query->paginate(20);

    return view('searchPage, ['categories' => $categories, 'queryResults' => $queryResults]);
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: why do you not have a pivot table to link `posts` and `categories`? seems you have a `category_slug` field on `posts`, how would that have multiple values? (how could a post have more than one category with your setup?)

Comment: @lagbox **category_slug** is a FK column of the **Posts** table which references to **slug** column in **categories** table. I think it doesn't need a pivot table because I only have 6 categories. also, a post only has one category type.

Comment: that column can only hold 1 value, so how could a post have more than 1 category?  *"if the user checks the photography **and** drawing category it only shows posts that have **both** categories"* ... how could a post have both?

Comment: I know a post only has one category type but I want to show something like this   ````select * from posts where category_slug = photography or category_slug = drawing````

Comment: that isn't both ... that is one **or** the other .... how about `whereIn` and you can pass an array of categories

Comment: @lagbox you are right I mean something like this. Please explain more if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to say that you want to find any `posts` that belong to any of the `categories` that are selected. You could use a `where` with `orWhere`s in it in a loop or use `whereIn`. Here is an example using `whereIn`:

```
if ($request->has('cate')) {
    $query->whereIn('category_slug', (array) $request->input('cate', []));
}
```

If you validate that the input `cate` is an array you can drop the `(array)` cast from that and the second argument to `input`.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Query Builder - Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) `whereIn`